# How to remove row from a customlistview

Tags: java, android, listview, button, adapter

I want to remove a row from a customlistview by pressing a button in the row that i want to delete. I put my code:

The **adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

/** VARIABILI */
int[] bandiera = {};
int[] positivo = {};
int[] negativo = {};
String[] piatti = {};
String[] qta = {};
String[] ntavolo = {};
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;
static int cambiobandiera=0; /** SE 0 E' VERDE, SE 1 E' ROSSA

/** COSTRUTTORE */
public Adapter(Context context, String[] piatti, String[] qta, String[] ntavolo, int[] bandiera,
               int[] positivo, int[] negativo)
{
    super(context, R.layout.rigatabella, piatti);

    this.c = context;
    this.piatti = piatti;
    this.qta = qta;
    this.ntavolo = ntavolo;
    this.bandiera = bandiera;
    this.positivo = positivo;
    this.negativo = negativo;
}

public class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView bandiera;
    TextView ntavolo;
    TextView piatto;
    TextView qta;
    ImageView positivo;
    ImageView negativo;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.rigatabella, null);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder();

    /** INZIALIZZO LE VIEWS */
    holder.piatto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.piatto);
    holder.ntavolo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ntavolo);
    holder.qta = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qta);
    holder.bandiera = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bandiera);
    holder.positivo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.positivo);
    holder.negativo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.negativo);

    /** ASSEGNARE I DATI */
    holder.bandiera.setImageResource(bandiera[position]);
    holder.ntavolo.setText(ntavolo[position]);
    holder.piatto.setText(piatti[position]);
    holder.qta.setText(qta[position]);
    holder.positivo.setImageResource(positivo[position]);
    holder.negativo.setImageResource(negativo[position]);

    holder.bandiera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cambiobandiera == 0) {
                holder.bandiera.setImageResource(R.mipmap.flagrossa);
                cambiobandiera = 1;
            } else {
                holder.bandiera.setImageResource(R.mipmap.flag);
                cambiobandiera = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    holder.positivo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //MAKE THE ROW TURNS GREEN
        }
    });

    holder.negativo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //REMOVE ROW FROM LISTVIEW
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

the **rigatabella.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bandiera" android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/flag"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_width="1dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ntavolo" android:text="tav."
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/piatto" android:text="Piatto"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qta" android:text="qta"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/positivo" android:src="@mipmap/conferma"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_width="1dp" android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/negativo" android:src="@mipmap/delete"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_width="1dp" android:gravity="center"/>
</TableRow>
```

The **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
String[] ntavolo={"2","4","3","5"};
String[] piatti={"Spaghetti allo scoglio","Lasagne","Cacca","Verdure miste"};
String[] qta={"2","4","1","1"};
int[] bandiera={R.drawable.flag, R.drawable.flag,R.drawable.flag,R.drawable.flag};
int[] positivo={R.drawable.conferma,R.drawable.conferma,R.drawable.conferma,R.drawable.conferma};
int[] negativo={R.drawable.delete,R.drawable.delete,R.drawable.delete,R.drawable.delete};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    /** ADAPTER */
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, piatti, qta, ntavolo, bandiera, positivo, negativo);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

So how to do it? i show a picture that represent what i mean:

[image]

Comment: remove the row from the list of data , then update you listview

Comment: yes but how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, rather than storing each part of the data in a different array you should be storing them in an Object that represents each row then have an arraylist rows in your adapter.

```
public class Row {
    private int bandiera;
    private int positivo;
    private int negativo;
    private String piatti;
    private String qta;
    private String ntavolo;

    public Row(int bandiera, int positivo, int negativo, String piatta, String qta, String ntavolo) {
        this.bandiera = bandiera;
        this.positivo = positivo;
        this.negativo = negativo;
        this.piatti = piatta;
        this.qta = qta;
        this.ntavolo = ntavolo;
    }
}
```

Next you'll need some changes to your adapter to use a list of Rows instead of the arrays you have.

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

/** VARIABILI */
ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
Context c;
LayoutInflater inflater;
static int cambiobandiera=0; /** SE 0 E' VERDE, SE 1 E' ROSSA

/** COSTRUTTORE */
public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Row> rows)
{
    super(context, R.layout.rigatabella);
    this.c = context;
    this.rows = rows;
}

public int getCount() {
    return rows.size();
}

public Row getItem(int position) {
    return rows.get(position);
}

public class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView bandiera;
    TextView ntavolo;
    TextView piatto;
    TextView qta;
    ImageView positivo;
    ImageView negativo;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Row row = getItem(position);
    // Here use row to fill in your textviews etc. You'll need to add getters to the Row model


    holder.negativo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rows.remove(position); // This removes the row from the dataset
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // This tells the adapter to update (to show the change on screen)
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

On your activity you'll need to create a list of Row objects using the arrays you currently have

```
ArrayList<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i < ntavolo.length; i++) {
// This is not very safe. If any of the arrays are smaller than the ntavolo array it will crash
    row.add(new Row(bandiera[i], positivo[i], negativo[i], piatti[i], qta[i], ntavolo[i]));     
}
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, rows);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To fill in the details in getView you'll need to add getters to the Row class provided and use those to fill in your textviews etc.

```
holder.ntavolo.setText(row.getNtavolo());
```

Comment: this is very good! but "piatti" is red on  super(context, R.layout.rigatabella, piatti); also can you tell me an example on how to fill using row? i am not good at programming

Comment: also i put my MainActivity.java to show i filled values

Comment: I've added some explanation of how you could use the arrays in your activity to create the adapter and how to use the row to fill in details

Answer (score 0):

When you have done the first answer, create an OnItemClickListener for the right view "negativo". This item listener deletes the object in the Array (and the string). Then update the list. Good luck!